# How to protect a vulnerable Family Member?

Tags: malware, privacy, phishing, remote-desktop

I apologize if this isn't the best exchange to be asking in, but I'm a little new at this.

**Problem:** A close relation outside my local area with declining cognitive function is demonstrating increasingly poor infosec practices. I have a plan to try preserver their online freedom while keeping them reasonably safe, but have no idea if it's any good.

**Details:** Relation has issue with poor impulse control, and frankly a long unaddressed history of terrible infosec. They have multiple email accounts, some dating back decades, and little to no hesitation about opening extremely questionable attachments. I am aware of at least one successful remote access phishing attack. They are prone to visiting sites that pose security threats.

**Devices:** The user works mostly on a windows machine,and has an iOS phone. The residence also has an OSx (x86) machine, other iOS devices, and a small number of networked devices. (printer/smart tv/etc.)

**My Skill Level:** Technically competent w/ limited coding skills, but decent hardware skills. Little to no experience with network management or Linux. I *do* have an embarrassing abundance of free time at the moment.

**Current Plan:**

- Toss the users current system after an expert retrieves critical files from it
- Hardware authenticator & password manager
- Purchase a subscription-based anti-virus program
- Implement DNS filtering via PiHole to block malicous IPs
- Setup remote access behind a VPN. (Preferable with a simple hardware switch to start & stop the service that also shoots an sms to me)
- Harden the Pi with something like Tripwire IDS & Rkhunter
- Wipe/factory reset all networked devices to the best of my ability
- Find/implement a method to segregate the users computer from other networked devices
- Attempt* to migrate the user to a new set of email address, or at least retire the most dangerous ones
- Attempt* to revoke the user's administrative access
- Attempt* to migrate the user's from windows to OSx or even Chrome OS**

*I say attempt, not due to a lack of technical knowledge, but with regards to user buy-in.

**The user has previously resisted a proposed migration to a chromebook, on the basis they will lose access to excel.

I would greatly appreciate any and all feedback this community could offer. As a novice, I'm well aware I may be missing low hanging fruit or pursuing wildly impractical solutions.

Comment: Keeping good backups is a good idea, especially of valuable files. So in case of a ransomware infection (which is very likely to occur), not all is lost

Comment: My experience transitioning an older relative from Windows to Linux was quite positive.  Most people only use email and a web browser these days, so it makes it easier.  So, yes, OSx, Chrome, Linux, take your pick, any of them will improve the security posture.

Comment: Speaking of the elderly, these days we call OSX "macOS" :)

Comment: I went through something like this in the past. Technically, maintain backups. The biggest issue we had was removing financial access. We did this when we saw him looking for his credit card to respond to a popup claiming a virus was detected yadda yadda. Good Luck!

Comment: *Toss the users current system after an expert retrieves critical files from it* .. **and removes storage devices for secure safe-keeping**

Comment: Tripwire/rkhunter is overkill for this threat model.

Comment: What's the purpose of a VPN here? Commercial VPNs don't really increase security, and the privacy benefits are debatable.

Answer (score 2):

1. I suggest replacing the Windows computer with an iPad. Because the relative already uses an iPhone, the transition shouldn't be too difficult for them, because a lot of software paradims and apps are the same on iPadOS as they are on iOS. It's also more way more difficult to harm yourself compared to traditional computing platforms like Windows, macOS or Linux, because you need to install apps from the App Store and software is heavily sandboxed.
2. They can use [iCloud Keychain](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204085) to generate and fill-in secure passwords, because this solution is free, built into the OS and very easy to use. In iOS 15 Apple added an option to use it for 2FA codes too. If you want an option that can store other types of sensitive information in addition to passwords (like notes), allows for organizing it with folders and tags and and has easy sharing with other people, I suggest commercial [1Password](http://1password.com) or open-source [Bitwarden](https://bitwarden.com).
3. They can use [Hide My Email](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210425) to generate a separate address for each account or website. Safari suggest it when filling out a form and it's also available in the Mail app.
4. You can use [Private Relay](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212614), which works for Safari and Mail.
5. You can use [NextDNS](http://nextdns.io) to block website (unlike Pi-Hole it will work with Private Relay if you install an encrypted DNS profile).
6. You don't need an antivirus if you go with the iPad approach.
7. Turn on [iCloud Backup](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211228) for their Apple Devices. For non-apple devices find other methods (but make sure it happens automatically, without them having to think about it).
8. Set up two-factor authentication for their Apple account and all other important accounts. You can set yourself as an [recovery contact](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212513), so you can help them if they loose access to their Apple ID.
9. You can use [Yubikey](https://www.yubico.com) for 2FA, for extra protection agains phishing. If you go this route, make sure at least two keys are set up with each account, in case they loose one.